# Miniature tension rod?

Tags: screws, hanging, fastener

I need to hang a (light) decoration temporarily between two irregularly shaped stone outcroppings. I'm looking for something like a tension rod that I could place between the two stones (and would hang the decoration from the tension rod). The space between the stones is only about one inch.

Is there anything like that on the market? When I search for tension rods, I only find those used to hang curtains, and they are way too big.

This is supposed to be a temporary hanging, I can't modify the stones, and since the stone is irregular, those temporary glue hooks won't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the gap is such that one could insert a mechanism into the space, a rock climbing cam may be an answer. The item is sold in sizes based on the width of the crack in the rock to be bridged/wedged. They are astonishingly expensive, but considering that one's life is hanging from this device, perhaps not so much.

A quick search shows some priced as low as US$20 and a few in the US$40 range, but most are outtasight for the aforementioned reasons.

You'd be able to insert the cam into the gap, tug it into place, spreading the load bearing segments and attach substantial weight to the fixture. When done, remove the decoration and push or tap upward to release the cams.

If you live near rock climbing regions, an outfitter shop would have stock. You could ask if anyone has a worn or otherwise useless device, as you would not be putting your life on that line.

Comment: Climbing nuts are cheaper than cams; no moving parts. A single hex should be very affordable, but it will be easiest to shop locally so you get the right size.

Answer (score 1):

This may not work for your particular situation, but it's the holidays, and it might help someone else.  There are little metal clips that I've always just known as "brick clips" that come in two styles:

[image] [image]

The first type is made for standard sized square bricks, but the second kind will work for any size bricks as long as they have a somewhat regular mortar line.  They can be found by searching for "brick clips" and are sold at the typical home improvement stores.  Great for temporary or light duty use.

Answer (score 0):

What about a wooden wedge driven between the two surfaces.